# Exporting gltf animation fails

Tags: export, gltf

I only want to export a simple animation as a proof of concept for my game engine to render. The animation I've created is only a rotating cube:
[image]

My export settings are the default ones:
[image]

All I've done is create two location, rotation keyframes, then I go to File->Export->gltf/glb and I get this crash report:

> Python: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/share/blender/3.6/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/**init**.py",
> line 697, in execute
> from .blender.exp import gltf2_blender_export   File "/usr/share/blender/3.6/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_export.py",
> line 14, in 
> from . import gltf2_blender_gather   File "/usr/share/blender/3.6/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather.py",
> line 10, in 
> from . import gltf2_blender_gather_nodes   File "/usr/share/blender/3.6/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py",
> line 13, in 
> from . import gltf2_blender_gather_tree   File "/usr/share/blender/3.6/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather_tree.py",
> line 6, in 
> import numpy as np ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Blend file:
[image]

I'm using Blender 3.6.5 on Fedora Linux.

Comment: Please share your Blend file.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it. Having said that, it might be worth updating to the latest [3.6 LTS](https://www.blender.org/download/lts/3-6/) version of Blender which is currently 3.6.8 in case any bugs in the exporter have been fixed since your version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `No module named 'numpy'`

This is not related to glTF specifically. Blender ships with the numpy module, so if you don't have it, there is a problem with your Blender installation.

Linux distros often have problems packaging Blender. Instead of installing Blender through your package manager, I strongly recommend you download it from the Blender website: https://www.blender.org/download/releases/3-6/

Comment: Yes. It was a problem with my blender installation. I installed it from the website instead of the package manager and it works now.